# iOS - Facebook won't authenticate old users (Incorrect value)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login

We are using Django framework called "AllAuth" to authenticate our users through Facebook and Twitter. 
For unknown reason some of our users get "Incorrect value" error when they try to login again in our app. This is not happening for new users.

I manage to troubleshoot it and I noticed that if I change the permissions (eg. added permission for "Location") in iOS SDK or if I delete our app from Facebook Apps I was able to connect successfully. So I guess it has to be something with the token for our old users. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the error now but some of our clients still can't login.

Is there any way to "re-request" user's permission from iOS SDK?

**Update:**

The error is

> The access token is invalid since the user hasn't engaged the app in
>   longer than 90 days

It's a know issue of Facebook and there is an open ticket for [that](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/194772814474841/)!

Comment: “Incorrect value” doesn’t sound like an API error message, but rather like something issued by your app itself, when something goes wrong. So first of all you should find out what actually went wrong.

Comment: "Incorrect value" is a reply from AllAuth!

Comment: Still doesn’t change the fact that you first of all need to figure out where this occurs, and what exact API response triggered it.